# Is there an command to sum values. I don't want to use join just simple adding Y+X like that

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Y
FROM fypcqex.open_cases
WHERE IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-AUG-20' AND '2-OCT-20';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS X
FROM fypcqex.open_cases
WHERE IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-SEP-20' AND '2-OCT-20';
```

suppose Y (42) and X (25) i want add these values but i don't know how also i don't want to use join

much appreciate your help

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: sorry i'm using this platform for the first time as you can see my code i have two count values Y and X i want to sum these values without using join

Comment: In SQL you are free to compose obfuscated but more or less working queries, so you always can use scalar values and functions on scalar values in `SELECT` list. But it almost always is poor performing and has more robust solution.

Comment: Why would you want to double count cases in September?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For an oracle database you can use something like

```
 SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Y
 FROM fypcqex.open_cases
 WHERE IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-AUG-20' AND '2-OCT-20')
 +
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS X
 FROM fypcqex.open_cases
 WHERE IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-SEP-20' AND '2-OCT-20') as sum
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Despite that it is a working solution and direct answer to the question, but the task has more transparent and better performing solution with single access to the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-AUG-20' AND '2-OCT-20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) y
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-SEP-20' AND '2-OCT-20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x
      --
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-AUG-20' AND '2-OCT-20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN IssueOccured BETWEEN '1-SEP-20' AND '2-OCT-20' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [y+x]
FROM fypcqex.open_cases
```